# Using SELECT in INSERT in Derby SQL

Tags: sql, derby

I have the following SQL code to create and populate a few tables in Derby:

```
CREATE TABLE GROUPS (
    GRP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    GRP_NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR(256));

CREATE TABLE USERS (
    USR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    USR_NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR(256));

CREATE TABLE USR_GRP_MEMBERSHIP (
    USR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES USERS ON DELETE CASCADE,
    GRP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES GROUPS ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT USR_ID_GRP_ID UNIQUE (USR_ID, GRP_ID));

INSERT INTO GROUPS(GRP_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME) VALUES('Users', 'Users');
INSERT INTO GROUPS(GRP_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME) VALUES('AdminUsers', 'Administrators');
INSERT INTO USERS(USR_NAME, PASSWORD, DISPLAY_NAME) VALUES('user', 'userpwd', 'User');
INSERT INTO USERS(USR_NAME, PASSWORD, DISPLAY_NAME) VALUES('admin', 'adminpawd', 'Administrator');

#The following code populates the USR_GRP_MEMBERSHIP table using the IDs of users
#& groups inserted in the previous set of insert statements

INSERT INTO USR_GRP_MEMBERSHIP VALUES((SELECT USR_ID FROM USERS WHERE USR_NAME = 'user'), (SELECT GRP_ID FROM GROUPS WHERE GRP_NAME = 'Users'));
INSERT INTO USR_GRP_MEMBERSHIP VALUES((SELECT USR_ID FROM USERS WHERE USR_NAME = 'admin'), (SELECT GRP_ID FROM GROUPS WHERE GRP_NAME = 'Users'));
INSERT INTO USR_GRP_MEMBERSHIP VALUES((SELECT USR_ID FROM USERS WHERE USR_NAME = 'admin'), (SELECT GRP_ID FROM GROUPS WHERE GRP_NAME = 'AdminUsers'));
```

My Question is: The last 3 `INSERT` statements have the `SELECT` statements repeating in them. How do I store the output of those SELECT statements in a variable and use them in these 3 `INSERT` statements?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use placeholders in prepared statements?

Here's a good starting point: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Your statement would then look something like:

```
INSERT INTO USR_GRP_MEMBERSHIP 
VALUES ((SELECT USR_ID FROM USERS WHERE USR_NAME = ?), 
        (SELECT GRP_ID FROM GROUPS WHERE GRP_NAME = ?));
```

and you would replace the placeholders with 'user'/'Users', 'admin'/'Users', 'admin'/'AdminUsers' at runtime by using SetString (twice) and then ExecuteUpdate, for each pair.

Comment: Yes this could be done, but that would be in JAVA code, I am looking for a way to do this in the SQL code itself! :)